# In cucumber, How to run Examples(of scenario outline) for multiple values(outer for loop has 2 counts)

Tags: testing, automation, cucumber

## Below example should run for 2 times by taking values :'warnings' and 'errors'

```
     Scenario Outline: Verify the response of actionDefinitionJson for the <Severity>
         When I update the action type to "<ActionType>"
          Then verify the response of actionDefinitionJson "<Response>"
      Examples:
          | Action Type        | Response       |
          | Condition         | null           |        
          | Auto-Mapping      | null           |
          | Builder           |expected        |
          |Editifiers         |actual          |

      tried this
           When I update the action type to "<ActionType>" and the values
          | Severity      |
          | warnings      |
          |  errors       |
        Then verify the response of actionDefinitionJson "<Response>"
        And a response with 200 is returned
        Examples:
        ` | ActionType        | Response       |
          | Condition         | null           |        
          | Auto-Mapping      | null           |
          | Builder           |expected        |
          |Edifiers           |actual          |`

     and this 
       Examples:
     `    | ActionType        | Response       |Severity      |
          | Condition         | null           | warnings     |        
          | Auto-Mapping      | null           |errors        |
          | Builder           |expected        |              |
          |Editifiers         |actual          |              |
```

this is not working for two iteration(of examples) of Severity values `